# Using case in converting rows to columns

Tags: mysql, rows

I have this case query where it converts rows to columns. My other case query like this works perfectly but on that other query
I'm getting the average of the values and for this I don't need to get the average but the actual values.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
  ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN value END),2) Col1,
  ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN value END),2) Col2

FROM table
WHERE id IN ("1",  "2") and 

DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) BETWEEN '2014-04-01'
AND '2014-04-01'
and value is not null

GROUP BY
DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) DIV 3
```

I tested it first using just the first case

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
  ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN value END),2) Col1
```

This worked and showed me the values but when I tried adding the second column,

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
  ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN value END),2) Col1,
  ROUND((CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN value END),2) Col2
```

The output on the Col1 are all null and the values for Col2 showed. I need it to show both values on both columns.
How can I fix this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` on the `case` values as you already are using a `group by` clause on the query.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
  ROUND( MAX( CASE WHEN id = '1' THEN value END ), 2 ) Col1,
  ROUND( MAX( CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN value END ) ,2 ) Col2
FROM table
WHERE 
  id IN ( '1', '2' ) 
  and DATE( from_unixtime( t_stamp / 1000 ) ) 
        BETWEEN '2014-04-01' and '2014-04-01'
  and value is not null
GROUP BY
  DATE( from_unixtime( t_stamp / 1000 ) ),
  HOUR( from_unixtime( t_stamp / 1000 ) )
```

Comment: is there a way where i don't have to use MAX?

Comment: Pivoting results null or custom values when a case is not matched. And for a summary you have to use any of the aggregate functions like max, count, avg, etc., as the case may be.

Comment: Is there another way where i can convert rows to columns without using case? Or maybe a select inside the case statement?

Comment: `CASE` is alternative to `IF(...`. But `IF..` is MySQL specific. And to convert rows into columns, you have to use any of these two in MySQL. No other way.

Comment: can you show me how the syntax would be if i would use `IF` and not CASE?

Comment: `ROUND( MAX( if( id = '1',  value, null ), 2 ) Col1,`. If you don't want to use `NULL` on a mismatch, use something like `''` or `0` but not `id` as it did not match. And better practice is `CASE` as it it is cross SQL compliant.